# Different admin backend

Tags: python, django, admin, backend

I'm new with django and I was thinking if it's possible to do a thing.

I know I can access to /admin/ and have django default admin but what if I want to create another admin interface with different URL using the default admin model/widget?

To be clear, new different interface will be for example /customer-backend and people who join it (what about permission?) have another graphical interface but using things (like validation) that are available in django admin backend.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a second `AdminSite` etc, but that will still be mainly a standard django admin. If you have more special needs, you'd possibly be better developping a custom one (using forms and ModelForms and possibly a couple generic apps for tables etc) - this is all standard django programming...

wrt/ validations and permissions, they are nothing specific to the `admin` app.

Comment: What do you suggest?
Because the second "admin" interface contains only partial info available into main default admin.
The main admin interface contains all with a simple graphic meanwhile the second one contains partial infos with another kind of graphics. The important is only that I can "import" admin default model and validations.

Answer (score 0):

[Django has capability to handle permissions](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/auth/default/). You can just create different permissions for different users. Users will access the admin section and only be able to view what they have permission to see. You don't need to create a separate admin for each permission requirement.

Comment: I understand but what about different graphic that I want to show? Like me with simple graphic and the other interface with a custom template.

Comment: @ManiUnzi Override the admin template (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/contrib/admin/#overriding-admin-templates). Change the logo based on user permissions, ex: if superuser then django logo, else custom logo.